# C++ python module (based on Pybind11) import error: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, pybind11

A C++ python module based on pybind11 library cannot be imported anymore in python. It was working until a few weeks ago but not any more (may be since the installation of miniconda). Cannot track the exact point when this stopped working as I was not using it since many weeks. I start python in the same directory as the module, and tried to import it in the terminal. And I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ld_pybind_d'
```

In the mean while I also tried:

- deleted the directory where miniconda was installed, rebuilt the module and linked it against python3.6m library.
- Created an empty __ init__.py file in the module directory
- Exported the current working directory in the PYTHONPATH environment variable

Other info:

- Built 64 bit version module and I also have 64 bit version python
- Python version 3.6.8

Nothing works .. Your help is very appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

As is, many times the case, if nothing really works, a restart would definitely do. I did that and seems to solve the case. Never the less, im just relieved it is loading now.